Generating RSA Signature in C# Without CRT Parameters Using System.Security.Cryptography or BouncyCastle
I'm working on a C# application (Framework 4.7.2, Visual Studio 2019, upgrading is not an option) that needs to generate a signature for a given sequence of bytes using RSA. My dataset contains only the Modulus, PublicKey, and PrivateExponent for the RSA keys. I understand that the other parameters (usually related to CRT optimizations) are not mandatory for RSA operations. However, I'm facing issues with both System.Security.Cryptography and BouncyCastle libraries when trying to generate a signature without these CRT parameters.
With System.Security.Cryptography, I attempted to use the SignData function, but it seems to require the CRT parameters, which I do not have. Similarly, when trying to use BouncyCastle, I couldn't make it work without these parameters either.
Is there a way to use
System.Security.Cryptography
or BouncyCastle to generate RSA signatures with only Modulus, PublicKey, and PrivateExponent, without CRT parameters?
Are there specific configurations or classes within these libraries that support RSA operations without CRT optimizations?
If anyone has encountered a similar situation, how did you resolve it or what workaround did you use?
Using System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate a signature with only Modulus, PublicKey, and PrivateExponent. This resulted in errors due to missing CRT parameters.
Attempting to use BouncyCastle's RSA implementation, but faced similar issues with the lack of CRT parameters.
This is the part of my code i refer to, i have a fixed set of keys to be used (must be this way). I search those keys in a certain structure and then attribute the parameters Modulus, Exponent and D.
RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
            for (i = 0; i<Constants.KEY_ID_TABLE_LENGTH_3072; i++)
            {
                if((SigKeyTbl_3072.keyIdTbl_3072[i].KeyId == keyId) && 
                  (SigKeyTbl_3072.keyIdTbl_3072[i].KeyType == keyType))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("KeyId found.");
                     rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = SigKeyTbl_3072.keyIdTbl_3072[i].PublicModulus.ToArray();
                     rsaKeyInfo.Exponent = SigKeyTbl_3072.keyIdTbl_3072[i].PublicExponent;
                     rsaKeyInfo.D = SigKeyTbl_3072.keyIdTbl_3072[i].PrivatExponent.ToArray();
                    return (ErrorCode: 0, rsaKeyInfo);
                }

In another part of the code i try to use my rsaKey like so:
                using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKey);
                    FscOut = rsa.SignData(fscIn, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
                }



Which gives me the following error message:
  Message: 
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'p')

  Stack Trace: 
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters.ValidateValue(BigInteger x, String name, String desc)
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters.ctor(BigInteger modulus, BigInteger publicExponent, BigInteger privateExponent, BigInteger p, BigInteger q, BigInteger dP, BigInteger dQ, BigInteger qInv)

If it is possible to use the library: System.Security.Cryptography with only those parameters that would be ideal.
However, how easy would it actually be to recover all the other parameters?

Is there a way to use System.Security.Cryptography or BouncyCastle to generate RSA signatures with only Modulus, PublicKey, and PrivateExponent...? Sure. But if you don't post your code, it's impossible to say what you've done wrong. So post your code, preferably with sample data, and describe the problem.

It's also relatively easy to recover all the CRT parameters if you have the private and public exponents and the modulus.

Modulus and public/private exponent can be processed directly by RsaKeyParameters(), which in turn can be processed directly by RsaDigestSigner#Init().

This question is similar to: Calculate primes p and q from private exponent (d), public exponent (e) and the modulus (n). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Topaco I don't understand. I have tried that and it also says that the values can't be null. The result seems to be the very same. Could you explain me in a little bit more detail please?

I have tried that and it also says that the values can't be null: Again, post your code with sample data for a repro (s. MCVE)! I can't reproduce your issue for BouncyCastle (unlike the native C# methods, BouncyCastle does not require the CRT parameters).
